# Selecting people to form a team of 6 from 8

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The question says:

> We wish to select $6$ people from $8$, if the person $\text{A}$ is chosen, then $\text{B}$ must be chosen. In how many ways selections can be made?

If we need to keep $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$ in our group, we need to choose $(6 - 2) = 4$ more from $(8 - 2) = 6$, as we already have $2$ people included.

The number of ways to choose : $^6C_4 = 15$.

Now, what if we exclude both $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$?

We have $(8 - 2) = 6$ people to choose from, and we need to choose $6$.

Number of ways to do so : $^6C_6 = 1$.

Both are mutually exclusive events, so Total number of selections : $15 + 1 = 16$.

But the answer key reports the answer is $22$.

What did I miss? Do we have to take $\text{B}$ in our team without $\text{A}$? The question says if $\text{A}$ is chosen, $\text{B}$ must be chosen, but there are no strict instructions to do the opposite one.

Actually, let's try.

We want to keep $\text{B}$, without keeping $\text{A}$. Then, we have $(8 - 2) = 6$ people to choose from, and we need to choose $(6- 1) = 5$.

The number of ways to do it : $^6C_5 = 6$.

The answer now matches, but who is wrong? Me, or the textbook answer? I found the last addition kind of irrational.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

**Edit**: While Excluding $\text{A}$, $\text{B}$ has already been chosen, so we have remaining $6$ to choose from, **not** $7$. It was an error I made in the first version.

Comment: The statement, "If $A$ is chosen then $B$ must be chosen" permits the formation of teams that include $B$ but not $A$.  So your last calculation is correct.  Incidentally, I'd probably perform the calculation by determining who's *not* included on the team, but what you did is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yes, That's what I like to think too.

Comment: You did make one error:  In the calculation in which $B$ is included but $A$ is not, you have six people to choose from since you already have $B$ and $A$ is not a permissible choice.

Comment: But if I already consider $\text{B}$ in my team, isn't the place already filled? We need to fill the rest $5$, with the remaining $6$ people. @N.F.Taussig

Comment: Oh, I found out the error. Silly me

Comment: Having found the error, Soumalya, you might want to write up what you now understand, and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Mr. Shore and Mr. Taussig, The instructions of the questions allows us to perform the calculation of "Including $\text{B}$ but not $\text{A}$", so We have $16 + 6 = 22$ ways of choosing.

Thanks for clearing my doubt on this one.

Comment: The textbook answer is correct for the reason that Robert Shore stated in his comment, namely that it is possible to form a team that includes $B$ but not $A$.

Comment: Wait a sec. I'm copying his comment [The statement, "If A is chosen then B must be chosen" permits the formation of teams that include B but not A]. So, Textbook one is correct? I seriously need sleep

Comment: Just to follow up on the rest of Robert Shore's comment, there are $\binom{8}{6}$ ways to select $6$ of the $8$ people.  To get the number of selections that satisfy the criterion that if $A$ is chosen, then $B$ must be chosen, subtract the number of committees that include $A$ but do not include $B$.  Since they include $A$ and do not include $B$, they must include five of the other six people, so there are $\binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{0}\binom{6}{5}$ such committees.  Therefore, the number of admissible committees is $\binom{8}{2} - \binom{1}{1}\binom{1}{0}\binom{6}{5} = 28 - 6 = 22$.

Comment: Shouldn't the total number of people be $\binom{8}{6}$ instead of $\binom{8}{2}$ you chose to subtract from? Doesn't matter, the values will be same. And thanks, this brings another way to solve the problem.

Comment: I did mean to write $\binom{8}{6}$.  Good catch.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, and the answer too.